# Issues with two Netgear R7450 routers on one network

Tags: home-networking, wired-networking

Fiber ISP wired to Netgear R7450 #1, from Router #1 it is wired to a TV, Bedroom PC and 5 port switch. From the 5 port switch it is wired to my home office PC and to a detached office space where the Netgear R7450 #2 is located.

Both routers are configured as if they are a single routers (out of the box setup), no special configuration.

##### The Issues:

No known issues within the home setup.

But in the detached office where I conduct all of my Zoom meetings I sporadically have "you network connection is unstable" warnings popup on my Zoom meeting or my Zoom connection completely disconnects and reconnects (WiFi drops and picks up again). I have had an IP Conflict warning pop up on my PC but after a restart of the PC everything was fine.

I only seem to have issue while in Zoom. If I am on YT or Netflix or Prime Movies or and other streaming service, no issues.

Speed tests are consistent, 450 down - 450 up, ping 2ms

This began all around the time I upgraded both routers to the R7450's and switching ISP's from Sprectrum - cable modem to a local CooP - fiber (Home Telcom). I upgraded routers to handle the fiber service.

This may not be router related but that's where I'm starting because that's the only thing that has changed recently.

Are there any further tests I can run or things to check before re-configuring routers?

If I have to re-configure my routers, what is the best solution for my setup?

Wiring Layout:
[image: Wiring Layout]

Router #1 Config:
[image: Router #1 Config]

Router #2 Config
[image: Router #2 Config]

Answer (score 1):

> Both routers are configured as if they are a single routers (out of
> the box setup), no special configuration.

That will put routers on different subnets and give you problems (default no connection between the two).

1. Hook up Router 2 to Router 1 via a LAN port.
2. Give Router 2 an address on Router 1.
3. Turn DHCP on Router 2 OFF.  This ensures just 1 DHCP Server. Multiple DHCP servers cause conflicts.

This is one standard and common way to hook up 2 routers on one subnet so as to readily communicate with each other. It is also reliable in the long term for interconnections.

Comment: Are saying the IP Subnet Mask will be different? I just checked both routers and they are both the same, 255.255.255.0  I have uploaded additional images showing the config of both routers.

Comment: Thank you for that. The process you listed above, do you have a detailed level of instruction for that as I'm just learning my way around the backend of my routers. I just want to make sure I'm configuring the second router correctly.

Comment: Thank you, Ill give it a try.

Comment: I ended up configuring router #2 as an access point. For now all is good. I have one other option that I was made aware of to try if I want to have control of the router #2's admin user interface. As an AP I lost that control.

Comment: The other option is to add a switch behind my ONT and have router #1 and #2 independent off the switch. My ISP provided 2 IP per fiber drop.